# Nested functions are disabled; use f-nested functions to re-enable

Tags: objective-c, nested

I am just learning Objective C and I am having great difficulty.  This is what is typed and it is giving me an error.  I typed the text that is bold.  What is wrong with it.  It gives me the nested function error right after `int main(void)`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// **#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
int amount = 1000000;
printf("The amount in your account is $%i\n", amount);
return 0;
}**
NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that C and it's brethren do not like functions within functions (putting aside `gcc` extensions for now).

What you seem to be trying to do is to declare a whole new `main` inside *your* `main`. That's a big no-no. What I suspect is that you've cut-and-pasted an entire C program into the middle of your existing `main`.

Start with:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int amount = 1000000;
    printf("The amount in your account is $%i\n", amount);
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

and work your way up from there.